# Expose nodejs restapi as library

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, frontend, backend

- I am working on POC where I have to find a way to expose rest-api implementation as a library so other projects can use this library easily...
- Problem statement - So, why I need this because my team is working on two project so 1. is a backend project where api is implemented, and 2. Frontend project they are using this api ...... so what's happening is that if api implemmentation changes done in backend project then the frontend project team has to import latest backend project again and again. so I want to create a library which is used directly by the frontend team.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not good way to optimize work with api.
Documenting REST API using Swagger will be better

Comment: i am not talking about documenting or swagger.... i want to convert rest api project to library like ...npm axios

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Calling and exposing rest api is not same thing. Swagger it is not only unified way to document api. You can use it to generate calls from client side. 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-js-codegen
https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-client